# Include button in a table view

Tags: button, controller

Here is my Code to list some values as tables

```
if(is_array($employeeworkschedules)){
            $i=0;
        foreach($employeeworkschedules as $employeeworkschedule){
            $i++;

            $retString .="<tr><td>".$i."</td><td>" . $employeeworkschedule['date'] . "</td><td class='hexshifttype'>" . $employeeworkschedule['shiftTypeName'] . "</td><td class='hexemployee'>" . $employeeworkschedule['employeeFName'] . "</td><td class='hexworkschedule'>" . $employeeworkschedule['workScheduleCode'] . "</td></tr>";

        }
        }
        echo $retString;
```

Here is my code for a button

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary">
      <a class="edit mdi mdi-eye text-primary" href="<?php echo base_url()?>workschedule/Editemployeeworkschedule/<?php echo $employeeworkschedule['employeeWorkScheduleId'];?>">Edit</a>
</button>
```

How can i include this button to the above given code.Please help me

Comment: you can create inside table

Comment: by simply create one <td> write the button inside the <td>..</td>

Comment: I created it <td><button class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                                   <a class="edit mdi mdi-eye text-primary" href="<?php echo base_url()?>workschedule/Editemployeeworkschedule/<?php echo $employeeworkschedule['employeeWorkScheduleId'];?>">Edit</a>
                                 </button></td>

Comment: But it shows undefined <

Comment: give $i++ end of the table

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($employeeworkschedules)){
            $i=0;
        foreach($employeeworkschedules as $employeeworkschedule){


            $retString .="<tr><td>".$i."</td><td>" . $employeeworkschedule['date'] . "</td><td class='hexshifttype'>" . $employeeworkschedule['shiftTypeName'] . "</td><td class='hexemployee'>" . $employeeworkschedule['employeeFName'] . "</td><td class='hexworkschedule'>" . $employeeworkschedule['workScheduleCode'] . "</td><td <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">



            Edit
         </button> "</td></tr>";
$i++;
        }
        }
        echo $retString;
```

Comment: you want to keep button inside a table

Comment: give your demo example using jsfiddle

Comment: Same error occured .syntax error, unexpected 'btn' (T_STRING)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183047/discussion-between-esakkichandra-and-unknownhacker).